# Primefaces onclick and oncomplete event in a selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a **selectBooleanCheckbox** of primefaces that performs an activation process that can delay and I want to add a progress bar or load image in the meantime from start (onclick) until when the java process is completed (oncomplete).

My idea at first was as follows:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{name}" id="check" onclick="PF('progressBar').show()" oncomplete="PF('progressBar').hide(),>
    <p:ajax update=":form,:progressBar"
            listener="#{bean.activate}"                                 
            process="@form" />                                                                  
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

But I have seen that p: selectBooleanCheckbox does not have the **onclick** and **oncomplete** events as other primefaces components they have, just the onchange event so it doesn't work for me.

What would be a valid option for a case like this? 
The alternative I have thought of would be to run the primefaces script from my java bean just before and after the process.
Another option that I have discarded is the JSF selectBooleanCheckbox since it does have the onclick attribute but not the oncomplete attribute

Comment: Did you check https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml ?

Comment: or [ajaxStatus](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml)

Comment: Move the `onclick` to the p:ajax `onstart` and move the `oncomplete` to p:ajax and it will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution using only Javascript and not Java doing it the JSF AJAX way.

This was the OP's original intent but didn't realize you needed to put the "on" methods on the AJAX call and not on the component itself.

```xml
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{name}" id="check">
    <p:ajax update=":form,:progressBar"
            listener="#{bean.activate}"                                 
            process="@form" 
            onstart="PF('progressBar').show()"
            oncomplete="PF('progressBar').hide()" />                                                                  
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: On the commandButton and link due to the included ajax there it needs to be on them. It confuses people ;-)